# Shaky electric guitar sound

Tags: electric-guitar, pick-ups

Recently, I started getting very unnerved with a shaky/wobbling sound I get out of my ESP LTD Snakebyte with EMG JH pick-ups. Especially noticeable starting from 7th-8th fret, but an open E5 (D#5) still floats a bit and loses power. Tried to lower the pick-ups, but no significant effect on the wobbling.

Here, a sample played in the neck pick-up:

Has anyone dealt with this? Any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm hearing what you are with the wobbling, but you could also try adjusting the action (distance between the strings and frets) to see if that helps. If the guitar's got a trem, try blocking it or tightening it to see if you can isolate where the noise is coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about 0:15 in? I hear it most there.

Since you rule out the pickup height...

**How old are your strings?**

If there's any age or cruft to them try a fresh set. It'll only cost you $4, and usually anytime I get "weirdness" like this it's because of the strings themselves. The clean clip sounds pretty dead, that's what makes me think the strings may be a bit old. If not, make sure your action is set right, the truss rod isn't vibrating, and isolate it to see if it's the amplifier or not (since it's most noticeable with the distortion channel). Also, you have quite a bit of gain, with a lot of midrange it seems. You may just have some really overwhelming overtones coming out of your setup, an EQ tweak could squeeze this out.

Answer (score 0):

Check the seating of the saddles the strings rest on at the bridge (and the nut slot seating for open notes) to make sure there is good contact between the string and bridge. We want the most surface contact with the strongest connection for vibration to resonate and sustain through the body of the guitar. This is in addition to the comment made by Jamie, all good suggestions.